# Align texts to the left with posts' thumbnails?

Tags: css

I use private blog for testing

https://helplogger.blogspot.sg/2012/03/auto-read-more-with-thumbnail-for.html

My texts do not align to the left with posts' thumbnails. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How can I correct this?

Comment: This is not the right question related to any javascript/programming

Comment: Hey, Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to include some code directly in the question (as well as a link to a page showing the issue if available too) as that usually results in an answer being provided quicker. From a quick look it seems like this is either of these 2 things: 1) A CSS issue where clearing is not happening properly. 2) A content issue where there is unintended whitespace in the markup. It is hard to say which for certain as I cannot see the problem on the sample url.

Comment: (All codes Script and CSS stated in the link)
https://helplogger.blogspot.sg/2012/03/auto-read-more-with-thumbnail-for.html
Fake experts cannot read codes talk so much, no solutions to correct the glitch, Texts Alignment?